# How to use .join() and .format() together in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use .join() and .format() together in the same loop, but unable to do so.

Sample Data:

```
somelist = [[{'web': 'www.example.com'}], [{'web': 'http://www.example.com/content/vb'}, {'123.123.3968 ': 'tel:123.123.3968'}], [{'web': 'https://example.com/fsdds/'}, {'': 'mailto:abc.xyz@ddaa.com?subject=Inquiry from abc.com%20'}], [{'web': 'https://example.com/svsd'}, {'web': 'http://example.com/vsdv'}, {'098.765.4321 ': 'tel:098.765.4321'}, {'B': 'mailto:xssc.xyz@ddaa.com?subject=Inquiry from xyz.com'}]]
```

Filtering out phone number as below:

```
phn = []
for lst in somelist:
    ph_check = []
    for ph in lst:
        ph_check += [val for val in ph.values() if re.match(r'tel:\(?(\d{3})\)?[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4})', val)]
    phn.append(', '.join(ph_check) if ph_check else '')
```

I want to format the phone number in the below format, can anyone suggest me how to pass the below format:

```
"{} {} {}".format(ph_check.group(1), ph_check.group(2), ph_check.group(3))
```

Getting output as: `tel:123.456.7890`

But I want the output as: `123 456 7890`

Comment: provide sample data you run this on

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887398/mirronelli, I have updated the sample data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phone_nr = "tel:123.456.7890"
phone_nr[4:].replace('.', ' ')
```

Result:

```
123 456 7890
```

This makes:

```
import re

somelist = [[{'web': 'www.example.com'}], [{'web': 'http://www.example.com/content/vb'}, {'123.123.3968 ': 'tel:123.123.3968'}], [{'web': 'https://example.com/fsdds/'}], [{'web': 'https://example.com/svsd'}, {'web': 'http://example.com/vsdv'}, {'098.765.4321 ': 'tel:098.765.4321'}]]

phn = []
for lst in somelist:
    ph_check = []
    for ph in lst:
        ph_check += [val for val in ph.values() if re.match(r'tel:\(?(\d{3})\)?[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4})', val)]
    phn.append(', '.join(ph_check)[4:].replace('.', ' ') if ph_check else '')
```

Comment: Thank you. Similarly, if I go ahead with email id what changes should I need to mak to find group(1). Code: em_check+ = [val for val in em_dct.values() if re.match(r'mailto:([\w\.]+@\w+\.\w+).*', val)]
    email.append(', '.join(em_check) if em_check else '')

Comment: You can split the e-mail on `?` and keep the first part: `email.append(', '.join(em_check).split('?')[0] if em_check else '')`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I took from index no. 7 for em_check as email.append(', '.join(em_check)[7:].split('?')[0] if em_check else '')

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually returning anything from the regular expression, you are using it to search for a telephone number and if one is found it's being added to ph_check.

Any way, to get the format you want you could remove 'tel:' and replace the '.' with ' '.

```
    ph_check += [val[4:].replace('.', ' ') for val in ph.values() if re.match(r'tel:\(?(\d{3})\)?[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4})', val)]
```

Or you could change the regular expression so it does return the 3 groups of numbers in the telephone number.

Comment: The regular expressions looks correct to me, each group will be captured by surrounding parenthesis, have a look at https://regex101.com/r/2dFCdg/1/. The provided code checks if the pattern exists but does not extract any groups. But this is probably what you were referring to in the last sentence?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the regular expression, it will find the phone numbers correctly but it isn't being used to return them. To do that you would need to use findall or access the groups() property of the Match object it currently returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all phone numbers in the desired format i would suggest this:

```py
import itertools as it
rgx = r'tel:\(?(\d{3})\)?[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4})'

[" ".join(*x) for x in [re.findall(rgx, x) for x in it.chain(*map(dict.values, it.chain(*somelist)))] if x]
```

output:

```
['123 123 3968', '098 765 4321']
```